# ctrl + click not working on Mac

Tags: javascript, angularjs, macos, window

In Angularjs application if user holds `ctrl` then `click` on hyperlink I am trying to open in new window, else it should open in the same window.

I have written the code but it only works on `windows` machine and not working on `MAC` i.e. safari/chrome.

Here is the below JS code

```
vm.goToDetails = function ($event) {
    if ($event.ctrlKey || $event.keyCode == 91 || $event.keyCode == 224){
        $window.open('/entry/' + vm.config.id + '/', '_blank');
    } else {
        $state.go('entry-details', { entryId: vm.config.id, query: vm.query });
    }
}
```

HTML CODE

```
<a class="title" ng-click="$ctrl.goToDetails($event)" data-ng-bind="$ctrl.config.entryTitle"></a>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try **metakey** for mac like this

```
if ($event.metaKey || $event.ctrlKey || $event.keyCode == 91 || $event.keyCode == 224) {
    $window.open('/entry/' + vm.config.id + '/', '_blank');
} else {
    $state.go('entry-details', { entryId: vm.config.id, query: vm.query });
}
```